# Huggingface datasets map() handles all data at a stroke and takes long time

Tags: python, nlp, tokenize, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-datasets

**1. Background**

Huggingface datasets package advises using `map()`  to process data in batches. In their example code on pretraining masked language model, they use `map()` to tokenize all data at a stroke before the train loop.

The corresponding code:

```
with accelerator.main_process_first():
    tokenized_datasets = raw_datasets.map(
        tokenize_function,
        batched=True,
        num_proc=args.preprocessing_num_workers,
        remove_columns=column_names,
        load_from_cache_file=not args.overwrite_cache,
        desc="Running tokenizer on every text in dataset"
    )
```

**2. The problem**

Thus, when I try the same pertaining code with a much larger corpus, it takes quite a long time to tokenize.

Also, we can choose to tokenize data in `data-collator`. In this way, the program only tokenizes one batch in the next training step and avoids getting stuck in tokenization.

**3. My question**

As described above, my questions are:

- **Which is better? Process in `map()` or in `data-collator`**
- **Why huggingface advises `map()` function?** There should be some advantages to using `map()`

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: When you tokenize during training, you increase the training time drastically. It is, therefore, advised to avoid expensive operations because GPU time is more expensive than CPU time.